# How many different values in an 2d array recursively ,java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I've been trying to figure it out for a long time now and I just couldn't.. so here I am reaching out to you.
I got a premade method that reacives a 2d array and returnes integer.
Each number in the array represent a color. The numbers range between 0 and 9.
My job is to return how many different"colors" are in the array recursively.
It's allowed to use other methods of my own to help , but the main idea should be recursive.
*If I want to use the premade method as a helping method , I have to use overloading.

If something was misunderstood please let me know and I'll fix it (English is not my first language).
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you mean that if 0, 1, ... 9 all appear somewhere in the array, the answer is 10?  And the answer would be less than 10 only if one or more of the numbers is missing from the array?

Comment: I just wonder why its a 2D array? Whats the contents of the second dimension?

Comment: Sorry, but if you spent so much time on thinking ... then show us the code you created so far. Right now, it still could be that you just drop your homework assignment here; hopping to find somebody doing your work for you!

Comment: I suggest: Pass a `BitSet` to your recursive method, an empty one in the first call. Then have your method add each colour encountered to your `BitSet`. Afterwards the number of elements in the `BitSet` (number of true bits) is equal to the number of different values in the array.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a recursive function which will take 2 indicies of array as an argument and save the result somewhere.
Something like

```
public void rec(int i, int j) 
{
 // some base condition 
 if (i <= width && j <= height) 
 {
   // do some calculations for example:
   result = result + diff(a[i][j]);              
   // something like this that will simulate the iteration like in for loop
   if (i == width && j < height) rec(0, j + 1); else rec(i + 1, j);     
 }
}
```

Comment: Now that you decided to do his homework, what is that `diff()` method doing?

Comment: That was actually a slight hint ... you see, when answering on low quality questions, you want to give super great quality answers. So that people see any sense in upvoting your content. As of now ... nope.

Comment: I just wanted to help with the idea of how it can be used in 2d array. For me recursion was not so straight-forward topic in the beginning of my journey :)

Comment: Hey again guys. I think you are exaggerating a little bit. Im not in school anymore and I have no purpose of letting you do my assignment because I will learn nothing from it. I'm missing out  the main idea of recursion and I had no code to show you. All I needed is a direction and guidance, which now I have . So thanks for those who decided to help :)